# Logging an event with Fabric SDK in Unity

Tags: ios, events, unity-game-engine, sdk, google-fabric

I am building a game for iOS platform in Unity. I have successfully imported Fabric SDK (crashlytics and answers). I am facing a problem when I am trying to write functions for logging an event. There is always an error shown like here:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA5T6.png)

Function is written and recognized correctly (suggested when starting to write functions name). Any ideas what could cause that sort of errors? 
Could the reason be, that events are not activated yet on the dashboard (I am not the admin, so I can not activate them by myself).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code for:

```
Fabrics.Answers.Answers.LogLevelStart("name of a level");
```

This should do the trick.